# How to retrive data from server using NIO

Tags: java, android, mysql, client-server

I have a project that requires me to create a Java server which will be connected to a MySQL database. This server is going to handle requests from clients, to send them data from the database. 
The request from the clients will be:

- check if a User is registered in the database
- add User to the database
- get a list of Users and which of them are on-line(this is where I use the HashMap)

After some searching I've concluded in using NIO, so I won't get too many threads to handle multiple Client requests. **My problem is that I can't understand how you can retrieve data from the channel** when you want to send, for example, a List or a HashMap. I mean, I've seen how the read(buffer) method works. I just can't understand -for example- how do you get th HashMap object back from the buffer, or how you retrieve any kind of "structured" data for that matter. If someone could explain(maybe with an example), that would be fantastic.

Maybe there is another way to communicate the data that I need, that would be easier for me to understand. I don't know. Your insight is greatly appreciated.

P.S. : My problem isn't that I don't get it because of the NIO, I have the same problem with the typical Input/Output Streams.

I should mention that the actual project is to create a Java server and the clients will be android devices. But since I'm a bit of a newbie, I thought I'd start off by testing the communication between two desktop, Java, applications before going for the android.
I mention this because I've seen something about Java RMI that allows you to use methods of your server remotely, but I think that you can't use it in Android.

Comment: Perhaps you want to serialize the `HashMap` to bytes first ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read and write objects using the serialisation mechanism. The classes that are involved are ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream. They are stream based though, so they don't fit well in the nio model. They are covered in the official tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/objectstreams.html

An alternative is using Google protocol buffers.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I'm taking a look at Google Protocol buffers now. Will come back after I'm done with the examples/tutorials.